# Customize Back Button for all Appearances in the App

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I want to change the appearance of all Back buttons in the app by setting the text to "Back" and removing the arrow (even just removing the arrow would be fine). I'm trying to find a way to do it globally for all view controllers in the app while also keeping the functionality (I don't want to create a new instance of a `UIBarButtonItem` and having to set the `selector`).

I created a custom `UINavigationController` and tried to set the back button title there with `navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.title = "Back"`, but it didn't work. Any suggestions how to do it properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create `CustomNavigationController` then at 
`override open func pushViewController(_ viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool)` do `controlClearBackTitle` method

then use  `CustomNavigationController` to fix it all in your app

[image]

```
import UIKit

class CustomNavigationController: UINavigationController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override open func pushViewController(_ viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        controlClearBackTitle()
        super.pushViewController(viewController, animated: animated)
    }

    override open func show(_ vc: UIViewController, sender: Any?) {
        controlClearBackTitle()
        super.show(vc, sender: sender)
    }

    func controlClearBackTitle() {

        self.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = UIImage()
        self.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = UIImage()
        topViewController?.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "AnyTitle", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this should do it. Try putting it in your custom NavigationController.

```
let backImage = UIImage(named: "backImage")
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = backImage
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = backImage
```

**EDIT**
Sorry totally forgot about title. This should do it:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backItem?.title = "New title"
```

Comment: Awesome, this removes the arrow! Any ideas how to change the title as well?

Comment: @smeshko Smeško I updated the answer, try it out. :)